# Как согласуются числительные?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Пожалуйста: *Он захватил 264 пленных немецких солдат и офицеров.* А если бы не было *пленных немецких* - *Он захватил 264 солдата и офицера* или тоже *солдат и офицеров*.

Как в данном случае согласуются числительные? А в каком падеже стоят существительные - в Винит.? А у числительного падеж?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Определение, стоящее после количественных числительных 2,34, при сочетании с существительным мужского рода ставится в родительном падеже мн.ч.: три известных бизнесмена. Ср. За последние три года. - За три последних года.

Comment: Меня интересует захватил в плен 264 немецких солдат или солдата (264 оканчивается на четыре, то получается четыре солдата)

Comment: Правильно: солдата. При числительных два, три, четыре существительное употребляется в родительном падеже единственного числа: два стула, три портрета, четыре книги. Обратите также внимание на ошибку, которую указал Слава.

Comment: Серж, "он захватил в плен 264  немецких солдат и офицеров" - это правильно или нет? Мн.ч. для "солдат и офицеров" при сочетании с числительным на четыре. А ед.число "264  немецких солдата и офицера" как-то плохо сочетается.

Comment: Вера, составные числительные, оканчивающиеся на два, три, четыре, управляют в И.п. и В.п. формой Р.п. единственного числа существительных (ср.: надо купить двадцать два компьютера, я вижу двадцать два студента. Согласен, что плохо сочетается,но такого правило.

Answer (score 5):

> Он захватил 264 пленных...

ПРАВИЛЬНО: ***Он захватил в плен...***

Comment: Логично. Тогда и вопросы не возникнут.

Answer (score 0):

Он захватил в плен немецких солдат и офицеров - их было 264.

Он захватил в плен 264 немца - солдат и офицеров.

Он захватил в плен немцев - 264 солдата и офицера.

Он захватил в плен 264 военных - немецких солдат и офицеров.

Он захватил в плен 264 человека - немецких солдат и офицеров.